# Tkinter window resizing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to resize a window based on how much text there is/are in a/some label(s). Here is what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7rP9.jpg. I want this window to get as big to fit all the text inside.
I have been looking for parameters from the Label from tkinter but nothing seemed to work. Some help would be much appreciated, thank you.

This is some of the code I have done:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

header = 'Staff requirements'
text = ['bla bla', 'bla bla']

window = Tk()
window.title('{}'.format(header.capitalize()))
window.geometry('400x200') # 80 + (x*15)

title_frame = Frame(window, borderwidth=2, relief='solid')
title_frame.pack(pady=10)

title_lbl = Label(title_frame, text=header.capitalize(), padx=5, pady=5, borderwidth=1, relief='solid', font=('Calibri', 15))
title_lbl.pack()

content_frame = Frame(window, borderwidth=1, relief='solid')
content_frame.pack(pady=10, padx=10, fill='y')

for sub_text in text:
    content_lbl = Label(content_frame, text=sub_text, padx=5, pady=5, wraplength=360, justify='left', font=('Calibri', 10))
    content_lbl.pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
window.geometry('400x200')
```

to :

```
window.geometry('')
```

Also , if you want to prevent the user from resizing the window , you can try :

```
window.resizable(False,False)
```

Comment: Yep, worked perfectly! May I ask though, the title of the window doesn't all fit. Is there a fix for that too?

Comment: No i am sorry , there is no standard way. Tkinter has no way of knowing how long the title is on the titlebar. The OS has completely control of that portion of the window . So you might notice it will look differently on other OS

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to find the Entry method, be careful with the geometry...

```
import tkinter as tk
guiApp= tk.Tk()
guiApp.geometry("630x630")
textPlace= tk.Entry(guiApp)
textPlace.place(x = 10,y = 10,width=600,height=600)
guiApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever to what I asked. There's 2 different variables that you use as your 'guiApp'. Also, I am not trying to use any entry fields so I do not need to use the Entry method. Lastly, I don't want to place the window anywhere, I want to resize it to the size that the text takes up (as shown in the picture, the text is overlapped).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your code snippet...In any case, I did mention you to be careful with the geometry.